# Команда для написания ОС

Tags: windows, macos, ассемблер, c, linux

Подскажите, какую примерно команду нужно собрать для написания ОС.
И, если возможно, с комментариями к каждому человеку (что будет делать, за что отвечать).
**Пожалуйста:**
Никаких отговорок от данной затеи, никаких реплик мол я такой идиот что это затеял. По факту.
Простой интерес.

Comment: [тут][1]


  [1]: http://www.xakep.ru/post/28794/

Comment: Там руководство по написанию. Это мне не требуется.

Comment: Похоже, что автор имел ввиду команду - в смысле "группу людей". :) Посмотрите на опыт хотя бы Линуса Торвалдса, и сколько человек работали на старте и сколько работает сейчас. (И это только работа с ядром!) Начинал он один :)

Answer (score 4):

Смотря какую систему хотите писать. Думаю, простейшую систему (в смысле ядро) может написать и один человек. А если с нуля полноценную ОС общего назначения да с графическим интерфейсом, то несколько тысяч разработчиков, 2-3 года + несколько миллиардов $.

Кроме того, ОС бывают разные: общего назначения, реального времени, распределенные, встроенные. Тут своя специфика будет и свои специалисты.

Answer (score 3):

Команда разработчиков на начальном этапе - не больше 3-5 человек. Это на этапе грубого проектирования. После того как стало понятно из чего все состоит и как будет работать (примерно 1-3 месяца) - подключаются еще 2-3 разработчика же и все вместе делают работающий прототип (страшный и уродливый, но по которому можно проследить основные особенности) - 2-6 мес. После этого (если проект все еще считается осмысленным) уточняется проект, набирается еще 10-15 человек, которые разбиваются на группы под руководством тех кто был в начале. Прототип отправляется на помойку и начинается собственно разработка.

Answer (score 1):

я думаю человек 20 - бородатых, олд-скулл прогеров в свитерках, которые вдоль и поперек знают винду, юникс, С++, ассемблер. И тогда возможно за полгодика получится что-то типа ДОСа

Comment: Только не С++, а чистый С.

Comment: ))) все это фигня, Болдженос же написал 10ти классник ))))

Comment: Очевидно это был http://lurkmore.ru/Денис_Попов ?)))